# Editing mode animation doesn't work well in UICollectionViewListCell with XIB

Tags: ios, swift

Using `UICollectionViewListCell` with `UIListContentConfiguration.valueCell`, enables us to achieve editing mode animation in `UICollectionView`

```
private typealias CellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Checklist>

private func initCellRegistration() {
    cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration(
        handler: { (cell: UICollectionViewListCell, _, character: Checklist) in
            var content = UIListContentConfiguration.valueCell()
            content.text = character.text
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
            
            var accessories: [UICellAccessory] = [
                .reorder(displayed: .whenEditing),
                .delete(displayed: .whenEditing, actionHandler: { [weak self] in
                })
            ]
            
            cell.accessories = accessories
        }
    )
}
```

### Using `UICollectionViewListCell` with `UIListContentConfiguration.valueCell`

[image]

---

However, such a methodology has a shortcoming.

I am not able to define my own custom UI elements.

I would like to have a `UIButton`, and a `UITextView`.

I tries to use the following methodology.

```
private typealias CellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<ChecklistCell, Checklist>

private func initCellRegistration() {
    self.cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<ChecklistCell, Checklist>(cellNib: ChecklistCell.getUINib()) { cell, indexPath, item in
        cell.update(item)
        
        var accessories: [UICellAccessory] = [
            .reorder(displayed: .whenEditing),
            .delete(displayed: .whenEditing, actionHandler: { [weak self] in
            })
        ]
        
        cell.accessories = accessories
    }
}

class ChecklistCell: UICollectionViewListCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func update(_ checklist: Checklist) {
        textView.text = checklist.text
    }

    static func getUINib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

It almost work. But, the custom UI elements is not being "pushed", when the delete/ reordering accessories appear. Please refer to the following video.

### Using `UICollectionViewListCell` with XIB

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can resolve such a limitation? Thank you.